# How to use vue2.0 attribute with Data-attribute

Tags: vue.js

I am new to vue2, I am trying to learn and implement it inside our EPUB format. But the problem is that EPUB parser does to allow custom tags / custom components.
e.g. I cant use `<li v-for="friend in friends">` in my HTML file as the parser will give error for `v-for`.

So I want to know if there is any way so that I can write whole vue2 code + tempalte inside .js and later append it to DOM?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, with ES6's `` ` `` you can write templates including line breaks in a single string, and then assign the string to the [`template` option](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#template).

However, you can use babel to transpile your code before the EPUB parser runs (so there won't be any v-for), check out the [guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CLI). And sure setting up the took chain require some effort, you can use the pure js option if your app is not too complicated.